# AJAX responseText has no value

Tags: ajax, responsetext

Just trying to get a simple piece of javascript to work that outputs the contents of a file in the same directory as an alert.

```
<form id="form" method="post" onsubmit="newsubmission()">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <script>
    function newsubmission() {      
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { alert(xhttp.responseText); }
        xhttp.open("POST", "test.txt", true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
</form>
```

When I click the Submit button a message is displayed with no text. I've been working on this all day and tried every online tutorial without success. Finally out of ideas. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Better and easy to use a jQuery ajax

```
$.ajax({
url:"your url",
success:function(data){
        //do your stuff with response data here
      }
error:function(){
       //handle your error
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried using JQuery first but that also did nothing, so resorted to using Javascript. Might go back to JQuery once I got JS working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cause with your ajax syntax. Try this

```
   function newsubmission(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //for IE
    if(window.AciveXObject){
     xmlhttp  = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }else{
    // for modern browsers
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequset();
    }
    xhttp.open("POST", "test.txt", true);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
     if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
       alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
     }
    }

    xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Tried the above code exactly. Now getting the following error. ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequset is not defined. I've searched for posts with the same error but I don't understand how to implement the answers :-(

Comment: Update: found it was something to do with node.js or base.js. Did a search on my computer for both these files. Couldn't find them anywhere. Am I supposed to download them or can I reference them in my html to some URL?

Comment: Yes you can! but i don't have node.js. Some times it was case  with your text.txt file. But real world it isn't use. You should try with php or asp file for your ajax response. Did you know php or asp?

Comment: try again with removed this code in your script var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); --on line 3--             Don't worry!  :-)

Comment: Done but getting the same error cause the else statement is running. Sorry for the hassle. PS I also had to comment out the e.preventDefault(); statement cause it was throwing a similar error: ReferenceError: e is not defined.

Comment: You don't worry I've got this code. I'll try it and I'll give update code ok?

Comment: Do you know about the jquery? It is most powerful library of the javascript. If you done this with it, you have save your time by writing  a similar code..

Comment: I tried JQuery first (before I found how to debug in Firefox) but that didn't work for me. So decided to get the concept working in Javascript first since the syntax of JS is similar to c++/Java. Have tested the code above using EasyPHP as a server and uploaded it to http://www.atomz.host-ed.me/submissions.html. Maybe there's something I missed but it's still giving the same error.

Comment: The online website is still in development so the search and submit functions don't yet work. Plus the YouTube link is just a test.

Comment: Please could you send for me your email address and then i can send for you jquery and html code

Comment: There seems no way for me to safely give you my email address. According to Stackoverflow a chat room can only be opened once you reach 101 reputation. If I post my email address here it'll be scanned by spambots for evermore :o(

Comment: Or maybe all we have to do is keep adding comments until Stackoverflow invites us to open a chat room. Then we can go back and delete the superfluous posts.

Comment: Then shouldn't give me your email addr. here because your security reasons.

Comment: Meh, even auto-chat option requires more rep. My facebook is https://www.facebook.com/aaron.lowe.5680.

Answer (score 0):

it's contain some errors and i have fixed it now try this

```
<form id="form" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<script>
document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var xmlhttp;
//for IE
if(window.ActiveXObject){
 xmlhttp  = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}else{
// for modern browsers
 xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
xmlhttp.open("POST", "text.txt", true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
 if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
   alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
 }
}
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</form>
```

Comment: Still getting the error, ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequset is not defined.

Comment: Also getting warning, Use of getAttributeNode() is deprecated. Use getAttribute() instead. pointing to the base.js file. There is no file on my computer called base.js nor any file containing any reference to "base.js" but noticed Firefox (most recent) says source of the file is https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/player-en_US-vflYm48JC/base.js. Not sure if this is linked to the problem or a separate issue.

Comment: Also tested it in Chrome. Doesn't bring up any alert dialogue box either. I don't know how to debug in Chrome so don't know what the cause is with Chrome.

Comment: Are you tested this script in the server? like Wamp or Xammp?, This is not working when it running as normal HTML file

Comment: It isn't because this is working fine with my computer